# Jackson mapper with polymorphimsm

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have classes in following structure :

```
class Member {
      public long id;
      public String name;
      public String type;
      public Pet pet; 
};

public abstract class Pet {
}

public CatPet extends Pet {
     public int  age;
     public String color;
}

public DogPet extends Pet {
     public int age;
     public String breed;
}
```

I have to serialize the objects of class Member into JSON string and vice-versa. Can I somehow make the serialization such that serialization of object Pet in class Member will be dependent on member 'type'. If type = "cat" it should serialize/deserialize using class CatPet.

Comment: You can implement your own deserializer for this class. See this page: http://pilhuhn.blogspot.com/2013/07/custom-deserializer-in-jackson-and.html for more information.

Comment: Have a look at the Jackson Wiki: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you typically use annotation `@JsonTypeInfo` on base class, to indicate how polymorphic type information is to be used. And with that, things will "just work".